# Getting column names from dataset

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm trying to get the column names from a dirty dataset. The name of the column names start before the symbol "=". Is there a quick method to do this without looping over all the data?
[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er6s3.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

missing_values=["n/a", "na", "--"]

df = pd.read_csv("data/data_bestand_3.txt", sep="&", na_values=missing_values)
df.head()
```

Comment: Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('=').str[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're reading your first row as the header names. In the `read_csv` method, pass the argument `header=None`. Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to set your column names:

```
missing_values=["n/a", "na", "--"]
df = pd.read_csv("data/data_bestand_3.txt", sep="&", na_values=missing_values, header=None)

df.columns = df.loc[0].str.split('=').str[0].values
```

Comment: df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.loc[0].str.split('=').str[0].values] i used strip for removing the space before the column name